# Using redux toolkit's createAyncThunk with a a payload creator that returns a discriminated union

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to convert my redux application to use redux toolkit, and I'm running into trouble using `createAsyncThunk` with my existing API wrappers.

The problem seems to be that the APIs return type contains a discriminated union.

Here are the types:

```
type Ok<T> = {
    isOk: true;
    response: T;
};

type Err<E> = {
    isOk: false;
    error: E;
};

export type Result<R, E> = Ok<R> | Err<E>;

interface Agent { /* ...snip ... */ }
interface ApiError { /* ...snip... */ }

class AgentsClient {
    getAll(): Promise<Result<Agent[], ApiError>> {
        // ...snip...
    }
}
```

Here is the async thunk I am trying to create:

```
const fetchAgents = createAsyncThunk("agents/fetchAgents", async () => {
    return await new AgentClient().getAll();
});
```

I get an error for the second argument (`payloadCreator`) when calling `createAsyncThunk`

```
Argument of type '() => Promise<Result<Agent[], ApiError>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AsyncThunkPayloadCreator<Ok<Agent[]>, void, {}>'.
  Type 'Promise<Result<Agent[], ApiError>>' is not assignable to type 'AsyncThunkPayloadCreatorReturnValue<Ok<Agent[]>, {}>'.
    Type 'Promise<Result<Agent[], ApiError>>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<Ok<Agent[]> | RejectWithValue<unknown, unknown>>'.
      Type 'Result<Agent[], ApiError>' is not assignable to type 'Ok<Agent[]> | RejectWithValue<unknown, unknown>'.
        Type 'Err<ApiError>' is not assignable to type 'Ok<Agent[]> | RejectWithValue<unknown, unknown>'.
          Property 'response' is missing in type 'Err<ApiError>' but required in type 'Ok<Agent[]>'.
```

Has anybody ran into this problem before? Any ideas how I can get myself out of this while still being able to use my `Result<T, E>` type?

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: This _may_ be a known issue that we just merged a PR for, but haven't released yet.  Can you try out https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/pull/1449 and see if that CodeSandbox CI build fixes your error?

Comment: Thanks @markerikson, this PR fixes my issue! I added a temporary fix to my code to redeclare the AsyncThunkPayloadCreatorReturnValue and MaybePromise types to fix this.

Can't wait for this to be released so I can remove the hack!

Answer (score 0):

As per user @markerikson, this has been fixed in PR https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/pull/1449

I have a temporary workaround until the merged PR is released. I would check if it's been released before considering using this fix, but if anyone is desperate, I was able to fix this by redeclaring the AsyncThunkPayloadCreatorReturnValue and MaybePromise types.

```
import type { Dispatch } from 'redux';
import type { IsUnknown } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/src/tsHelpers';

class RejectWithValue<Payload, RejectedMeta> {
    private readonly _type!: 'RejectWithValue'
    constructor(
        public readonly payload: Payload,
        public readonly meta: RejectedMeta,
    ) {}
}

class FulfillWithMeta<Payload, FulfilledMeta> {
    private readonly _type!: 'FulfillWithMeta'
    constructor(
        public readonly payload: Payload,
        public readonly meta: FulfilledMeta,
    ) {}
}

declare module "@reduxjs/toolkit" {
    type MaybePromise<T> = T | Promise<T> | (T extends any ? Promise<T> : never)

    type GetRejectValue<ThunkApiConfig> = ThunkApiConfig extends {
        rejectValue: infer RejectValue
      }
        ? RejectValue
        : unknown
      
      type GetPendingMeta<ThunkApiConfig> = ThunkApiConfig extends {
        pendingMeta: infer PendingMeta
      }
        ? PendingMeta
        : unknown
      
      type GetFulfilledMeta<ThunkApiConfig> = ThunkApiConfig extends {
        fulfilledMeta: infer FulfilledMeta
      }
        ? FulfilledMeta
        : unknown
      
      type GetRejectedMeta<ThunkApiConfig> = ThunkApiConfig extends {
        rejectedMeta: infer RejectedMeta
      }
        ? RejectedMeta
        : unknown

    type AsyncThunkConfig = {
        state?: unknown;
        dispatch?: Dispatch;
        extra?: unknown;
        rejectValue?: unknown;
        serializedErrorType?: unknown;
        pendingMeta?: unknown;
        fulfilledMeta?: unknown;
        rejectedMeta?: unknown;
    };

    export type AsyncThunkPayloadCreatorReturnValue<Returned, ThunkApiConfig extends AsyncThunkConfig> = MaybePromise<IsUnknown<GetFulfilledMeta<ThunkApiConfig>, Returned, FulfillWithMeta<Returned, GetFulfilledMeta<ThunkApiConfig>>> | RejectWithValue<GetRejectValue<ThunkApiConfig>, GetRejectedMeta<ThunkApiConfig>>>;
}
```

Comment: You can also install the build from that PR and use it meanwhile. See https://ci.codesandbox.io/status/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/pr/1449 for install instructions.